# FirstOrDefault giving wrong incorrect result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm confused on how to fix this.

I want to display "no customer found" if **custID = 0**

```
@if (Model.Customer == null)
{
    <p>no customer found</p>
}
else
{
<p> @Model.Customer.CustomerName </p>        
}
```

Controller :

```
  public ActionResult Index(int custID = 0)  
        {
         var customer = (from c in db.Customers
         where c.Id == (custID == 0 ? c.Id : custID)
         select c).FirstOrDefault();    // .SingleOrDefault(); 

        routes.MapRoute(
                  null,
                  "AAA/Index/{custID}",
                  new { controller = "AAA", action = "Index" }, new { custID = @"\d+" });
```

Going to the URL "/AAA/Index/0" gives **record number ID = 1** in the table, and not null for no record with ID of 0.

I used SingleOrDefault and it errors with:

> Sequence contains more than one element

How come `FirstOrDefault()` in not giving me the default **null** value when the record for ' custID = 0 ' should not be found?

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with MVC, but wouldn't you just create an overload for `Index()` that doesn't accept any parameters, rather than using 0 as a pseudo customer ID?

Comment: @mason it's actually better to use `int? custId`.

Comment: Why do you need `(custID == 0 ? c.Id : custID)` in `where`? That would always be true if you pass in custID as 0.

Comment: @rageit I agree, has just come to the same conclusion: if `custID` is zero, then all customers are returned.

Comment: @Richard I was slower to even write the comment :)

Comment: "Why do you need (custID == 0 ? c.Id : custID) in where?" . .  it worked in another View, but I wasn't using FirstOrDefault() with the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `custID == 0` your condition looks like this:

```
where c.Id == c.Id
```

which is obviously true for any record. [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) fails because there is more than one, [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns the first one.

Probably you want just:

```
where c.Id == custID
```

or if your DB contains a record with `Id` equal to 0, but you don't want to return it:

```
where custID != 0 && c.Id == custID
```

Comment: And since no order is defined, it is returned in whatever order the database decides to return it.

Comment: So the problem is with the "where c.Id == (custID == 0 ? c.Id : custID)" clause?  I used this in another situation and it worked when I wanted the value of the parameter to be zero. But I wasn't using FirstOrDefault(). Any ideas on how I can fix this? thanks

Comment: @MikeHowe Hard to guess what are your intentions. I edited the answer with two suggestions.

Comment: @MikeHowe [Good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) let users know what results you want.  For example you might say, *if a value is passed, I want to search on that value, if a value is not passed, I want null returned*.

Comment: I would actually assume you'd just do `if (custId == 0) return null;`.

Comment: Just using "where c.Id == custID" worked. I was thinking too much and confusing this problem with another controller that I used this on but had different logic I guess. MVC is great but can get confusing at times.